# Tizen WebApplication failed to install on device

Tags: installation, command-line-interface, tizen

Sorry for my english.
I have an application and Samsung UE32M5500.

I do the following [CLI](https://developer.tizen.org/ko/development/tizen-studio/web-tools/cli) commands:

path to certificate

```
call C:\tizen-studio\tools\ide\bin\tizen.bat cli-config -g "default.profiles.path=...\profiles.xml"
```

packaging a Tizen Application with signing

```
call C:\tizen-studio\tools\ide\bin\tizen.bat package -t wgt -s zaykov_cert
```

connect to device

```
c:\tizen-studio\tools\sdb connect 10.5.0.119:26101
```

install app to device

```
call C:\tizen-studio\tools\ide\bin\tizen.bat install -n app.wgt -t UE32M5500
```

All commands are executed without errors, right up to the install command.

[result of install command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFa1G.png)

What could be the cause of the error?

If you install through Tizen Studio with the same certificate, then there are no errors. But when importing the project, there are no source files in the Tizen studio. There is only one huge main.js file and folder with media.

Answer (score 0):

Also Following this Tip&Tech document should help:

[Sample Web Application development using Command Line Interface](https://developer.tizen.org/community/tip-tech/sample-web-application-development-using-command-line-interface)

First of all, Set the Date/time correctly on both your PC and TV. connect your device using sdb first.Now, the Issue could be certificate related. I would suggest you to generate author and distributor certificate from Tizen Studio. (Install TV related & Certificate Manager related packages from package manager before that)

> From Tizen Studio > Tools > Certificate Manager > **+** > Samsung >
> **TV** > Create New Certificate Profile (suppose 'x') > Create New author certificate > Sign In to Samsung Account > You will be notified
> location of your author certificate (Suppose C:\x\ )(May be a hidden
> folder, select 'show hidden folders' to explore )
>
> Create New distributor certificate > (your TV should be on the DUID
> list) > > You will be notified location of your distributor
> certificate (Same C:\x\ )

Let's get back to CLI. As explained on [Managing Security Profile Section](https://developer.tizen.org/development/tizen-studio/web-tools/cli?langredirect=1#Manage_sec_prof) of CLI Guide, Add new Security profile using the author & distributor certificates you just created using Certificate Manager tools. Example command:

```
tizen security-profiles add -n NewProfileX -a C:\x\author.p12 -p ******** 
-d C:\x\distributor.p12 -dp ********
```

Then Clean, Build, Package with NewProfileX profile, Install, Run.